# Formal method : []<> Infinitely often (Always eventually) in TLA

Tags: formal-methods

From my understanding in TLA, an eventual action (<>) is not allowing stuttering to be happened in next state. Then, is that means the next state variable is not allowed stuttering in the case of infinitely often ([]<>)?

Take the example of weather condition, infinitely often can be described as eventually many days in a year (we don't know when it will happen) will rain but the weather must be sunny after the raining day?

Is my understanding towards infinitely often right? Correct me if I am wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The property `[]<> ϕ` is verified by any trace that

- has infinite length and
- does not verify `<>[] ¬ϕ`, **i.e.** there is not point in time after which `ϕ` is definitively `false` forever

An infinite trace satisfying `[] ϕ` also satisfies `[]<> ϕ`, since the former is stronger than the latter. The converse is not necessarily the case.

**e.g.**

A statement like `[]<> it_rains_today` would be satisfied by the following traces:

- A trace s.t. it uninterruptedly rains every day all day, for all eternity
- A trace s.t. it rains every other day, for all eternity
- A trace s.t. it rains one day every 10 years, for all eternity
- A trace s.t. it rains one day every 10 million years, for all eternity

Note that there is no requirement for such event to happen with any kind of regularity, it is just easier to word examples like this. The **only requirement** is that there exists **no point in time after which it completely stops to rain forever**.

Comment: `A trace s.t. it uninterruptedly rains every day all day, for all eternity` Doesn't this mean it is raining forever? And doesn't this condition supposed belongs to `[]<> it_rains_today`?

Comment: @NgYk That's exactly what it means. An infinite trace satisfying `[] ϕ` also satisfies `[]<> ϕ`, since the former is stronger than the latter. The converse is not necessarily the case.